# Given the length of one diagonal of a parallelogram, find the distance between the centroids of triangles formed by other diagonal

Tags: geometry

Question take from [this image](https://ibb.co/h3zuiy):

> The length of diagonal $BD$ of a parallelogram $ABCD$ is $36$ cm. $P$ and $Q$ are the centroids of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADC$, respectively. What is the length (in cm) of $PQ$? (Choices: $6$, $9$, $12$, $18$.)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Help us help you, by telling is what you know about the problem and where you got stuck. (The screenshot has a "View Solution" button. What was that solution, and what about it wasn't satisfactory to you?) This information allows answerers to tailor responses to your skill level, while avoiding telling you things you already know. (It also helps dispel any suspicion that you're just trying to get us to do your homework for you.)

Comment: Interesting, one can drop the requirement that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and still get the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @AchilleHui notes, the parallelogram condition is unnecessary. Here's a solution for any quadrilateral:

[image]

Let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of $\overline{BC}$ and $\overline{DC}$; that is, $\overline{MN}$ is a mid-segment of $\triangle BCD$, with half the length of $\overline{BD}$. We "know" that centroids trisect medians; consequently, $\triangle PAQ \sim \triangle MAN$ with scale factor $2:3$, so that $\overline{PQ}$ has two-thirds the length of $\overline{MN}$. Thus,

> $$|\overline{PQ}| = \frac23 |\overline{MN}| = \frac23\cdot\frac12|\overline{BD}| = \frac13|\overline{BD}|$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

\begin{align}
|BD|&=|BP|+|PM|+|MQ|+|QD|
=2u+u+u+2u=6u=36
,\\
|PQ|&=2u=\tfrac{36}3=12
.
\end{align}